# Copy a column in CSV File and get the information from another csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

**Here is what I am trying to achieve** :
I have two CSV files currently. I am trying to copy just the column names of one csv file and the data from the second csv file (and then merge them into a third csv file OR over write the data in the first csv file).

The data doesn't get just copied over to the new file I have to move it around to a specific column. How would I go about doing this? I have done my research and tried various things but giving up at this point. Please help.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
    # =============================================================================
# with open(r'shipment.csv', 'rt') as f, open(r'names.csv', 'wt') as f_out:
#     reader = csv.reader(f)
#     writer = csv.writer(f_out)
#     for row in reader:
#         writer.writerow((row[1]))
# =============================================================================


import csv
import glob
import pandas
# =============================================================================
# 
# with open(r'shipment.csv', 'rt')as f, open(r'names.csv', 'wt') as f_out:
#     headings = next(iter(csv.reader(f)))
#     csv.writer(f_out).writerow(headings)
#     csvout = csv.DictWriter(f_out, fieldnames=headings)
#     for d in csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames=headings):
#         csvout.writerow(d)
#             
# =============================================================================

#opening shipment file.     
with open ('registration.csv', 'r')as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    print(csv_file)

    #skipping over the header
    #next(csv_reader)
    #opening new file for writing called newnames
    with open('1.csv', 'w')as new_file:
        fieldnames = ['Tube Barcode', 'Rack Barcode', 'Hole', 'Tube Comment', 'Compound Part 1', 'Compound Part 2', 
                      'Compound Part 3', 'Amount', 'Concentration', 'Solvent', 'Solvent Conc', 'Natural Product', 
                      'Ignore', 'Tube Labware Type', 'Rack Labware Type']

        #creating csv writer variable
        #using a writer method of the csvwriter to open up a delimeter -
        csv_writer=csv.DictWriter(new_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, delimiter=',')

        csv_writer.writeheader()
    #reading only the date underneath the first line.     
        for row in csv_reader:

            csv_writer.writerow(fieldnames[1])
```

Comment: kindly post your code

Comment: Use [csvWriter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: Added my current / tested code

Comment: Hmm, this looks like neither as true Python2 (csv.writer requires a file opened in *binary* mode), nor Python3, (csv.writer requires a file opened with `newline=None`). What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

csv1 = pd.read_csv(file1)
csv2 = pd.read_csv(file2)
csv1.columns = csv2.columns
csv1.to_csv(filename)
```

Comment: This is assuming the ordering of the columns is the same in both csv files